# Is there a way to graph with jQuery's flot with a data set that doesn't contain x values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

I have large amounts of data formatted in JSON formats, I recently scripted the data to conform to Flot's data set, except for one problem, the data has no `x` values.

EG:

```
{
  label: "testMetric1",
  data: [12,314,123,41]
}
```

I want to simply graph these values as `y` values. Is there a way to tell Flot to just assume the `x` series will be sequential (i.e. graph 12 at `x = 1`, graph 314 at `x = 2`, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to automatically have it do that, no.

So before you feed your data to flot, do something like this:

```
var data = [12,314,123,41]; 
var new_data = [];

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){  
 new_data.push([i,data[i]]); 
}

//then call flot here with new_data
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that you write a converter function that inserts the desired x values into your data for easy use with flot.